# Using LEFT FIND in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to fill cell F2 with the following formula `=LEFT(F1,FIND("-",F1)-2))`

I tried using `Range("F2").Formula = "=LEFT(F1,FIND("-",F1)-2))"` but get an error and from reading around see I'm supposed to use `InStr` instead of FIND in VBA, but as it's not as simple as a direct replacement I can't get it to work. Can someone please walk me through what I'm supposed to do here?!

Comment: You've got an extra parens in the formula, and you need to double up the inner quotes. `"=LEFT(F1,FIND(""-"",F1)-2)"`.

Comment: But do you want the formula or the actual value given by that formula? Why do you mention `InStr`? If you just want the value, try `Range("F2").Value = Trim(Split(Range("F1").Value, "-")(0))`

Comment: Thanks both, these solutions both worked.